# Check for number within a url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, hash

I've a gallery within a website and each gallery image is represented by a url like so:

http://www.example.com/gallery/my-photos#10

http://www.example.com/gallery/my-photos#11

http://www.example.com/gallery/my-photos#12

.
.
.
.
.

I've created a conditional statement to prevent user from invalid url.

```
var galleryNum = window.location.hash.substring(1);

if( typeof(galleryNum) == "string" || typeof(galleryNum) == "NaN" ){
    console.log('this is not a number');
}else if(typeof(galleryNum) == "number"){
    console.log('this is a number');
}
```

However this doesn't work, the value I get from window.location.hash.substring(1) will always be a string regardless I enter number or a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to get number, you should use:

```
parseInt(galleryNum,10)
```

if you want to check whether galleryNum is number or not, you can use:

```
isNaN(parseInt(galleryNum,10))
```

Comment: you should add the radix parameter: `parseInt(galleryNum, 10)`

Comment: Yes you definitley should use the radix parameter it does some unwanted things in older versions of ecmascript.

Answer (score 3):

Try utilizing `.test()`

```
if( /\d/.test(galleryNum) ) {
  // `Number`
} else {
  // not `Number`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no "NaN" type. In fact, despite NaN standing for Not-a-Number, it actually is a number: `typeof NaN === 'number'`

You can however use `isNaN()` to test for NaN.
To test if the string returned from the URL can be cast to a number, use parseInt:

```
var galleryNum = parseInt(window.location.hash.substring(1),10);
if (typeof(galleryNum) === 'number' && !isNan(galleryNum)) {
    // got a number here
}
```

Comment: This is true, but it still doesn't solve his problem.

Comment: You are right. I was focusing on an irrelevant part of his question.

Comment: That's okay it's good for him to know either way. It may be better suited as a comment though.